# Setting the right MYSQL table options

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a database table for user profiles. It's comprised of a primary key, user id, full name, email, location, and about me.

I'm having difficulty determining the correct options for this type of database table.

```
Storage Engine:   
Collation:
auto_increment:
row_format:
```

Currently I'm using InnoDB to allow foreign keys and that's the only option I'm certain about.

Comment: Have you [reviewed the `CREATE TABLE` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)?  It contains descriptions of all of those options and should give you an idea of what you should do with each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, phpMyAdmin's default setting are fine.

**Auto-increment** ist mainly used for primary-key id columns if type int, which should identify individual entires.

In case space is not of importance, you may set **ROW_FORMAT** to **FIXED**. This options restrict the storage size of each row in constant size of bytes - even if some columns are variable sized strings (varchar).

**Collation** and related settings is a bit complicated. I'd propose to use defaults or review the manuals.

Choosing between **MyISAM or InnoDB** isn't only a choice of features, but also of access patterns. Often MyISAM is fine, in certain other cases InnoDB is better. The choice should e.g. be influenced by the number and relative weight of reads and updates.